# How to group items by category and count?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing stats with `gem "groupdate", "~> 3.1.1"` and `gem "chartkick"`, and I need to know how many items were sold in each category. 
Here are my models and there associations.

**category.rb**

```
has_many :products
```

**product.rb**

```
belongs_to :category, optional: true
has_many :variants, dependent: :destroy
```

variant.rb

```
belongs_to :product
has_many :order_items, dependent: :destroy
```

order_item.rb

```
belongs_to :variant
```

I can find the category's title of an order item like so:

```
OrderItem.last.variant.product.category.title
```

But how from all the order_items, I can group the categories by title and count?

below is not working of course but that's my  try...

```
def order_item_category
 OrderItem.joins(:variant).product.category.group(:title).count
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join them properly as you need all records

```
OrderItem.joins(variant: [product: :category]).group('categories.title').count
```

This should give you the category wise count of the Order Items.

**Note:** You may also want to add the scope depending on if you only want order items in the completed state.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! and thanks for pointing the completed state :)